# SparkML: Pipeline predictions have fewer records than the input

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

How can I find out -- inside a pipeline -- which records are skipped or dropped from the transformation?

I have a pipeline which is like the following:

- StringIndexer
- OneHotEncoderEstimator
- (repeat above for all categorical cols)
- VectorAssembler (collecting all encoded and raw numeric cols)
- LogisticRegression

Then:

```
model = pipeline.fit(train)
predicted = model.transform(test)

test.count() 
8092
predicted.count()
8091
```

One record is missing and I'd like to find out which one.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `handleInvalid` option of your `StringIndexer` is likely set to `skip`.

You can change this option to `error` and the transform will fail on never seen labels. As of Spark 2.2 you can also use option `keep` to keep the rows with unknown labels in a separate bucket for them:

```
string_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="label", outputCol="indexed", handleInvalid='keep')
```